# how to pass new prop to rendered component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

say you have a rendered component named Banner;

```
var Banner = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     return { text: this.props.word };
  },
  render: function(){
     return <div>this.state.text</div>
  }
}) 

var banner = ReactDom.render( <Banner word="hello" />, document.getElementById('banner'));
```

Is it possible to update the props of Banner without replacing the component? as for example with the function below

```
function changeText(component, text){
    // change text inside banner
}
changeText(banner, 'Goodbye')
```

Obviously in this example it would be much easier to reinitialize a Banner with new text but I want banner to have animations when the text changes but not when it gets initialized

Comment: You could use [componentWillReceiveProps](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) and then [set some state](https://medium.com/react-tutorials/react-state-14a6d4f736f5#.p9hfmhflf) to indicate that animation should occur.  Obviously you need a mechanism of passing down new components into Banner.  You could for this create a wrapping component which polls for banner text or whatever and then sets the banner `word` prop.  React will do the rest.

Comment: Check out some tutorials. http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit to simplistic.  Your actual problem could be a number of things, but I'll take a stab at what seems most likely.

If the goal is to have the content of your div be modified, then the answer is not to use props at all.  That's exactly what your state is for!

```
var Banner = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>this.state.word</div>
    },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {word: this.props.word};
    }

    changeWord: function(word){
        this.setState({word: word});
    }
});
```

EDIT:

If you're trying to modify the component from vanilla js embedded elsewhere in the page:

I think your best bet in this case would be to leverage some (if not all) of the Flux design pattern: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content

If not the entire Flux paradigm, you could at the very least make use of the way Flux handles 'Stores', which are essentially just Node.js EventEmmiters: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

```
var BannerStore = new EventEmmitter();

var Banner = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>this.state.word</div>
    },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {word: this.props.word};
    },
    changeWord: function(){
        this.setState({word: BannerStore.word});
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        BannerStore.on('banner_change', this.changeWord);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function(){
        BannerStore.removeListener('banner_change', this.changeWord);
    }
});

function changeText(component, text){
    if(component === 'banner'){
        BannerStore.word = text;
        BannerStore.emit('banner_change');
    }
}
changeText(banner, 'Goodbye')
```

Using full flux paradigm will be cleaner in the long run, but is more than can be reasonably typed into SO.

Comment: But this will only work if the `Banner` "owns" that data, which it may very well not do. You'd have to find some way of injecting that data into the component without using props; any way I can think of seems very "un-React-y".

Comment: So where is the data coming from?  That seems like the crux of your question, but you haven't clued us in on it!

Comment: I am not the OP :-) In OP's example it appears he's passing the message from props.

Comment: haha, woops.  :O.  That's why I started my answer with a request for more info though.  Without knowing where the data is originating, any answer can be contradicted, because no one component will fit every conceivable need.

Comment: Where is that function?  A parent component?  Child component?  Completely separate react tree?

Comment: neither? It's just in the same file so it has a reference to banner

Comment: Updated my answer.